# is "there is no can doubt" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs, word-order

I'm really confused about this. I've asked 2 teachers and they somehow gave different answers, it was used like this:

> "…there is no can doubt that climate change has a..."

from what I know and looked up, it should be incorrect, but I don't know, a possible explanation might help.

Comment: *There is no doubt* that climate change…. The term “can” shouldn’t be in the sentence. Or rephrasing.. *No one can doubt that climate change*….

Comment: What is the source? Where did you find this phrase?

Comment: What were the teachers' answers? Were they saying the phrase was grammarical? I highly doubt that.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect. The correct version would be:

> There **can be** no doubt that climate change has a...

(Your teachers may have been confused by the idiom "no can do," which is a humorous saying precisely because it is grammatically incorrect.)